# how to use MAX in a query and use the result as a number in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

If I write a formula using query and limit it to one result, I can then use it as a number, for instance

```
=1+QUERY(B13:F18,"SELECT C WHERE (B='Banana') LIMIT 1")
```

But if I want to use the maximum value the same way, it gives me an error:

```
=1+QUERY(B13:F18,"SELECT MAX(C) WHERE (B='Banana')",0)
```

> Function ADD parameter 2 expects number values.  But 'max' is a text and cannot be coerced to a number.

Column C only contains numbers! If I exclude the addition I see that it is adding an unwanted label "max" above the max value.  I am putting 0 for the third parameter to query, which I thought meant I wouldn't have any header lines. I also tried "" and that didn't work either.

I thought maybe it was treating the result as an array, so I wrapped the whole thing with:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(...), 0, 1)
```

Which I expected to skip over the row containing max. But I got the exact same output!

How do I extract just the number so I can use it in the formula?

Comment: You need specifically QUERY? If not, you may use MAXIFS(C:C,B:B,"Banana")

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there is a better way to do it, but this works:

```
=1+QUERY(B13:F18,"SELECT MAX(C) WHERE (B='Banana') label MAX(C) ''",0)
```